# Why isn't Harry considered a pureblood?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry's magical parents are Lily Evans (a muggleborn) and James Potter (a pureblood). Since a pureblood is someone with magical parents, why isn't he considered a pureblood?

A muggleborn, or mudblood is a person with powers from an ancestor. A halfblood is a person with one parent that is magical. Given that Harry has **two magical parents,** why is he only a "half-blood"?

Comment: Per the [wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Half-blood); "*It should be noted that any wizard who is not either Pureblood or Muggle-born is considered a Half-blood, even if they have two wizard parents; they need not have exactly half-Muggle/half-wizard heritage."*

Comment: The logic goes like this:  If your magical ancestors have all been forgotten, you're a Muggle-born.  If your non-magical ancestors have all been edited out of your genealogical records, you're a Pureblood.  If neither is the case, you're a Half-Blood.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of definition, and  <strike>hearkens back</strike> is similar to the 'One drop Rule' that used to be well known in the US.  Basically, to be a pureblood, you must come from magical families on both sides, not just two magic-using parents.  Conversely, **any** muggle blood makes you 'half-blood' at best.

From Pottermore:

> "The term 'pure-blood' refers to a family or individual without Muggle
>   (non-magic) blood. The concept is generally associated with Salazar
>   Slytherin, one of the four founders of Hogwarts School of Witchcraft
>   and Wizardry, whose aversion to teaching anybody of Muggle parentage
>   eventually led to a breach with his three fellow founders, and his
>   resignation from the school."

None of the families are really pure-blooded, as Dumbledore points out in Beetle the Bard

> "So-called pure-blood families maintain their alleged purity by
>   disowning, banishing, or lying about Muggles or Muggle-borns on their
>   family trees. Then they attempt to foist their hypocrisy upon the rest
>   of us by asking us to ban works dealing with the truths they deny.
>   There is not a witch or wizard in existence whose blood has not
>   mingled with that of Muggles..."

Harry's Mother's family is not a recognized wizard family, so he has muggle-blood.  Any muggle-blood with wizard blood defines him as a Half-blood.

To go straight to the horse's mouth, here's JK Rowling on the subject:
(Note: This is from the Harry Potter Wiki, and I haven't been able to substantiate it as an actual JKR quote yet.)

> The expressions ‘pure-blood’, ‘half-blood’, and ‘Muggle-born’ have
>   been coined by people to whom these distinctions matter, and express
>   their originators’ prejudice. As far as somebody like Lucius Malfoy is
>   concerned, for instance, a Muggle-born is as ‘bad’ as a Muggle.
>   Therefore Harry would be considered only ‘half’ wizard, because of his
>   maternal grandparents. If you think this is far-fetched, look at some
>   of the real charts the Nazis used to show what constituted ‘Aryan’ or
>   ‘Jewish’ blood...the Nazis used precisely the same warped logic as the
>   Death Eaters. A single Jewish grandparent 'polluted' the blood,
>   according to their propaganda.

Comment: Was the "One Drop Rule" well known in the UK too? If it was just used for the US, I don't think that means much to Harry given that the American Wizarding World seems pretty isolated from the British one.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Dunno if it was well known in the UK, but my point was about the concept, not the term -- basically ANY muggle blood (even a single drop) made you not 'pure-blooded' per the perception of the 'Pure Blood.'  Updated the answer to make it clear that it wasn't necessarily an influence on JKR writing it.

Answer (score 1):

On account of his mother, Lily.

> A pureblood is someone with magical parents...A halfblood is a person with one parent that is magical.

You're *kind of* right. The criteria for Muggle-born and pureblood are pretty straightforward. Rowling is much more vague and inconsistent when it comes to half-bloods. You can be a half-blood either if one of your parents was a Muggle (and the other a witch/wizard) *or* if one of your parents was a Muggle-born witch/wizard. What matters is that at least one parent has some connection to the Muggle world, whether they remained a Muggle until their death or they later went on to become a witch or wizard.

In Harry's case, he counts as a half-blood on account of his mother Lily. She was a Muggle-born witch with two Muggle parents. That was enough to make Harry a half-blood.